# Mirage `passthrough` is not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I'm trying to use passthrough for a POST request in this Ember [project](https://github.com/linkedin/pinot/tree/master/thirdeye/thirdeye-frontend%60:)

```
this.passthrough('/thirdeye/entity?entityType=ANOMALY_FUNCTION');
```

This is what the call looks like in `app/mirage/config.js`.
I got the following error:

```
Mirage: Your Ember app tried to POST '/thirdeye/entity?entityType=ANOMALY_FUNCTION',
but there was no route defined to handle this request.
Define a route that matches this path in your
mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?
```

Clearly, I've added that call to the config file, but it's not being picked up. I read that `passthrough` only works for `>= jquery 2.x`, which my project is.

Does anyone know what else could cause this?

Answer (score 5):

I found out the problem was I had to do `this.passthrough('/thirdeye/***');` since the call has query params. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get passthrough working at all, the examples I saw for external URLs were just being ignored and the responses on Github were a bit vague. In the end I was able to use the function override for it to whitelist patterns matches:

```
this.passthrough(request =>
  [
    /amazon/
  ].some((regex) => regex.test(request.url)));
```

i.e. anything with `amazon` in the URL is ignored.

Note, include at the end of the `routes` function.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, I still don't know why it won't work with just this.passthrough('https://www.blah.com/blahdomain/**')